# Replacing dll driver and its integrity

Tags: c++, winapi, dll, driver, biometrics

I developed testing dll driver for Windows Biometric Framework. This driver takes care of storing fingerprint information.

WinBio uses 3 types of driver - engine,storage and sensor. These were installed with biometric sensor.

I'd like to replace storage adapter with my own. So I simply copyied my implementation to corresponding folder and changed value in registry to use my dll.
But when I test my application I get error at Opening Session that says

> The adapter binary did not pass its integrity check

What exactly do I need to make it work with my application?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Drivers need to be signed unless you have disabled this on windows boot. Also other parts could be checking whether the driver is corrupt or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to sign your plug-in driver - for testing you can use a test certificate you create using WDK tools.  Details can be found in the [Windows Biometric Framework: Code-Signing Guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/gg463093.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it immediatelly. A had copy of this document already  downloaded, but I forgot about it :)